# What happens to the callee's thread when an async function is invoked synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

In the below sample, when the async "Process" function is invoked synchronously, I can see the call to "await Task.Delay(1000)" causes the UI to hang.

I know I can avoid the hang by either calling "await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false)" or wrapping the "Process" invocation inside another task. I can understand the problem is with the synchornizationcontext, and I know await is doing something fancy with it i.e. if I replace the call "await Task.Delay(1000)" to "Task.Delay(1000).Wait()" the UI does not hang.

Can someone please explain the behavior (i did try looking at ildasm code but it didn't help). Thanks much.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

public async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    var task = Process();
    MessageBox.Show(task.Result);
}

public async Task<String> Process()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: In short: `task.Result` means "hang the UI until the task is complete, then use the result". `await task` means "yield control to my caller; when the task is complete, schedule the continuation of the task to run at a convenient time in the future, and use the result then".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, methods are always invoked synchronously. When `OnLoaded` is invoked, it invokes the `Process` method.

The `Process` method invokes the `Task.Delay` method and gets back a reference to a `Task<string>` object which it awaits. This means that the code after the `await` is executed later and that the `Process` method returns at this point.

The `OnLoaded` method gets back a reference to a `Task<string>` object which it stores in the  `task` variable. Then invokes the `Result` getter on the task. This blocks the current thread until the task completes.

One second later, the `Process` method tries continue. Because you started the task on the UI thread, the scheduler attempts to schedule the `Process` method on the UI thread. But the UI thread is blocked by the `Result` getter call, so the `return "";` statement is never executed.

Comment: Sorry but it is not the case, the UI hangs and return "" is not even invoked (please set a breakpoint and see it for yourself).

Comment: Thanks, not sure why it didn't click to me. :)

Comment: +1. I describe this deadlock in more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), and my blog post has links to more information including a couple of deadlock demos.